# How to run package in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5, package

How to run package in laravel 5?

I have downloaded one chat package from INTERNET. And, I have run command vendor:publish and it successfully published.

Now I don't know how to run that.

Comment: Could you share what package you are trying to run?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden: Here is the package name..cmgmyr/messenger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check whether the package ships with any service provider and facade. If so, add them in your config/app.php file. Package's service provider should go under **providers** array and facade should go under **aliases** array.

As soon as you specify providers under providers array, Laravel now know that you have called an external package, so it will load them. Thus, the package now will be available for your usage.

Comment: Please check the example files the author have mentioned here https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger#examples

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to run a package in laravel is:

1. add the package to composer.json file
2. then in terminal write composer dump-autoload